# pprint results of psycopg2._psycopg.Diagnostics

Tags: python, postgresql-9.2, psycopg2

I'm in my dispatcher handling responses from the server which includes psycopg2 diag objects. What's the best way to pprint (PrettyPrint) the `'psycopg2._psycopg.Diagnostics'` object  object to help me debug the ungraceful exceptions? It's string representation reflects it's type:`<'psycopg2._psycopg.Diagnostics'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out = {}
for prop in dir(e.diag):
    if not re.match(r'__', prop):
        out[prop] = getattr(e.diag, prop)
pprint.pprint(out)
```